# Dynamic Casting Using Java Reflection

Tags: java

I have two classes, as follows:

```
public class Person {
    private String dob;
    private PersonName personName;
}

public class PersonName {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

I am setting these values dynamically using Java Reflection.

First, I create an instance of `Person` and I set the value for `dob`.  After that, I need to set a `PersonName` value in `Person`.  So I created another instance of `PersonName` and I set the values in that `PersonName`.  After that, I am trying to set the `PersonName` instance in the `Person` entity.

For that I used code like this:

```
Class componentClass = Class.forName(clazz.getName());
Field field = parentClass.getDeclaredField(Introspector
                        .decapitalize(clazz.getSimpleName()));
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(parentClass, componentClass);
```

Here, `parentClass` is a `Person` instance and `componentClass` is a `PersonName` instance.  I am trying to set the `PersonName` in the `Person`, but I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.rise.common.model.PersonName field
com.rise.common.model.Person.personName to java.lang.Class
```

So how can I set the values dynamically?

Thanks.

### My Whole Code:

```
protected void assignProperties(List<Object[]> argResults,
        List<Class> argAllClassesList, Class argParentClass)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException,
        SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    List<Object[]> results = (List<Object[]>) Precondition.ensureNotEmpty(
            argResults, "Output List");
    List<Class<?>> personClassList = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    for (Object[] recordValues : results) {
        Class parentClass = Class.forName(this.getPersistentClass()
                .getName());
        parentClass.newInstance();
        int count = 0;
        count = assignValues(recordValues, parentClass, count);
        for (Class clazz : argAllClassesList) {
            Class componentClass = Class.forName(clazz.getName());
            componentClass.newInstance();
            String decapitalize = Introspector.decapitalize(clazz
                    .getSimpleName());
            Field field = parentClass.getDeclaredField(decapitalize);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            assignValues(recordValues, componentClass, count);
             field.set(parentClass, componentClass);
        }
        personClassList.add(parentClass);
    }

    for (Class<?> class1 : personClassList) {
        Class<Person> person = (Class<Person>) class1;
        System.out.println(person);
    }

}

private int assignValues(Object[] argRecordValues, Class argClass,
        int argCount) {
    String paramName = Introspector.decapitalize(argClass.getSimpleName());
    if (Precondition.checkNotEmpty(paramName)) {
        List<Field> fieldNames = TenantConfigHelper.getInstance()
                .getModelNameVsFieldsMap().get(paramName);
        try {
            for (Field field : fieldNames) {
                BeanUtils.setProperty(argClass, field.getName(),
                        argRecordValues[argCount]);
                ++argCount;
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return argCount;
}
```

Comment: And why do you want to do that? It looks like an XY problem.

Comment: `Class.forName(clazz.getName())` seems a little redundant.

Comment: Hay Paul, Why its redundant..?

Comment: @Amar: You have the class, and you're asking it this name, in order to get the class which has this name. But you had it from the start. `Class.forName(clazz.getName()) == clazz`.

Comment: Java reflections is not simple.  It requires a good basic understanding of the distinction between various concepts -- class, instance, reference, value, member, etc.  And, in particular, the documentation for the java.lang.reflect classes requires VERY careful reading, even for someone who is fairly comfortable with the terminology.  Slow down and take the time to understand it.

Comment: You don't need to do 'dynamic casting' to use Reflection to call methods with. You just need to supply arguments of the correct type to the `Method` being called. You aren't doing that, and the error message you are getting is 100% self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be some confusion over the difference between Java class definitions and instances at work here. You want to set the values of fields on particular instances, not the classes themselves. Something like this may work:

```
Object parentClassInstance = parentClass.newInstance();
Class componentClass = Class.forName(clazz.getName());
Object componentClassInstance = componentClass.newInstance();
Field field = parentClass.getDeclaredField(Introspector
                        .decapitalize(clazz.getSimpleName()));
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(parentClassInstance, componentClassInstance);
```

Looking at the whole code sample, however, it is a little hard to follow. Why have a `List` of `Class`es, with a name like `personClassList`, which would seem to indicate that each class should be the same class, `Person`? I feel it should probably instead be a `List<Person>` or perhaps `List<Object>`, which you would populate with your `Person` instances, not the `Class` objects themselves.

**Edit to answer the following question in a comment:**

> I have to return List instances insetad of List so how can I type case from Class to Person dynamically...?

You can't cast from `Class` to `Person`, since `Person` is probably not a subclass of `Class`.

Instead, declare your list as a `List<Person>` instead of a `List<Class<?>>`

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Then add the `Person` objects instead of the `Class` objects to your list at the bottom of your first `for` loop.

```
personList.add((Person)parentClassInstance);
```

And the loop at the bottom will need to change too:

```
for (Person person : personList) {
    System.out.println(person);
}
```

Comment: Hay Thanx with this change it was fine. But I have to return List<Person> instances insetad of List<Class> so how can I type case from Class to Person dynamically...?

Comment: Edited to respond to your question.

Answer (score 3):

The message explains what's wrong: componentClass is not an *instance* of PersonName. It's an object of type `Class` (probably `Class<PersonName>`). You probably forgot to instantiate the class.

Edit:

Your code does:

```
parentClass.newInstance();
```

and

```
componentClass.newInstance();
```

This is the equivalent of doing

```
new Parent();
```

and

```
new ParentName();
```

So it creates an instance, but doesn't assign it to any variable, and thus doesn't do anything with the created instance, which will be garbage-collectable immediately.

You want

```
Object parent = parentClass.newInstance();
Object component = componentClass.newInstance();
field.set(parent, component);
```

Comment: Hay thanx JB Nizet

I instantiate a class using class.forName("Path");

Comment: `Class.forName()` returns the class (i.e. `PersonName.class`). Not an instance of this class (i.e. `new PersonName()`). To get an instance, you must call a constructor.

Comment: I did the class.newInstance() method. But I forget to mention this step. Sorry for that.

Comment: Maybe you did, but your code is still wrong. Without seeing it, we can't tell you where and why. All we know is that componentClass is of type Class in the code you posted. So you're passing a Class, and not an instance.

Comment: Hay JB Nizet I just pasted my whole code and can you please tell me the problem but finally I need to return "List<Person>" objects...

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this same type of answer and basically what everyone is specifying with the Object is correct.   I also created a generic list like `List<Object>` instead of the actual class name.  Below is a function that returns a List of type Object's.  I pass in the class name and load that with the .loadClass. Than create a new object with that new class instance with the .newInstance.  The dList gets loaded with all the information for each objectClass which is the class I pass in with the className variable.  The rest is basically just dynamically invoking all of the "set" methods within that particular class with the values from the result set.

```
protected List<Object> FillObject(ResultSet rs, String className)
    {
        List<Object> dList = new ArrayList<Object>();

        try
        {
            ClassLoader classLoader = GenericModel.class.getClassLoader();

            while (rs.next())
            {
                Class reflectionClass = classLoader.loadClass("models." + className);

                Object objectClass = reflectionClass.newInstance();

                Method[] methods = reflectionClass.getMethods();

                for(Method method: methods)
                {
                    if (method.getName().indexOf("set") > -1)
                    {
                        Class[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();

                        for(Class pT: parameterTypes)
                        {
                            Method setMethod = reflectionClass.getMethod(method.getName(), pT);

                            switch(pT.getName())
                            {
                                case "int":
                                    int intValue = rs.getInt(method.getName().replace("set", ""));
                                    setMethod.invoke(objectClass, intValue);
                                    break;

                                case "java.util.Date":
                                    Date dateValue = rs.getDate(method.getName().replace("set", ""));
                                    setMethod.invoke(objectClass, dateValue);
                                    break;

                                case "boolean":
                                    boolean boolValue = rs.getBoolean(method.getName().replace("set", ""));
                                    setMethod.invoke(objectClass, boolValue);
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    String stringValue = rs.getString(method.getName().replace("set", ""));
                                    setMethod.invoke(objectClass, stringValue);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                dList.add(objectClass);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.setConnectionMessage("ERROR: reflection class loading: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return dList;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is more what the OP was looking for - a way to handle a generic list, a list of objects that can have multiple definitions. `instanceOf` could also be of use here.

Answer (score 0):

The type system is verified by the compiler.  While there is some additional safety possible during runtime, that additional safety is not even close to the safety the compiler imposes.  Which begs the question, Why?

Assuming you could get the stuff to work, exactly how would you be able to justify casting `class1` below into a `Class<Person>` type?  You *declared* it to be a `Class<?>`!

```
for (Class<?> class1 : personClassList) {
    Class<Person> person = (Class<Person>) class1;
    System.out.println(person);
}
```

Comment: Hay the for loop is wrong thing because its a List<Class>. I have an output of List<Class> each class object is nothing but Person object and I need to convert these List<Class> --> List<Person> dynamically. May be tomorrow I will do a type cast with another class but I will use this code as common code... So how can I achieve this...? Please tell me...

Comment: It sounds to me like you want dynamic type checking.  If so, you can't use Java's Class system; because, _it is meant to impose static type checking_.  Just make everything an Object, as it is the only type which everything shares, and then write in your own code to check whatever system you implement to check types at run-time.  But, please, stop trying to make dynamic run-time types exist statically.  It won't work.